how to check if annotation in type String is present or not?
I have a sample type annotation code below. I want to check the if the string variable is annotated or not using (string.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(SampleAnno.class)) but the return value is always false. But I have used this method for class annotations and it works.
Is there something wrong with my code? I just want to check if the variable is annotated with 'SampleAnno' or not. Thanks
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
 
@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)
 
@interface SampleAnno{}
 
// Main class 
public class Annotations {
   
    // Main driver method 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 
        // Annotating the type of a string
        @SampleAnno String string = new String("I am annotated with a type annotation");
        System.out.println(string.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(SampleAnno.class));
    }
}


how did you add the SampleAnno annotation to the String class ? That would require the source class of String being modified, compiled and loaded instead of the standard class -- in posted code you did annotate the local variable string, but not the String class

hi, yes i only annotate the local variable string and i want to check if the string variable has the '@SampleAnno'

I think that is not possible (with reflectiom) even if the RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME was used (the default is CLASS: "Annotations are to be recorded in the class file by the compiler but need not be retained by the VM at run time." (emphasis added))

The answers in the linked Q&A are outdated. Type annotations are stored in the class file for local variables. However, Reflection still does not support inspecting local variables, so you don’t get hands on that information with built-in APIs. You’d need to inspect the bytecode of the class.
